# Trying to refresh src link within iframe tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to refresh a iframe src link, only when the parent doesn't contain an active class. This is the code I have so far but, with which I am still getting an error:

TypeError: 'iframe'.closest is not a function. (In ''iframe'.closest('li active')', ''iframe'.closest' is undefined

```js
let frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
for (let i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
    let src = frames[i].src;
    if (!'iframe'.closest('li active')) {
        src = '';
    };
    console.log(src);
};
```

```
** html ** 

<div id="slide-window">
  
    <ol id="slides">
      
      <li class="slide color-0 active">
          <iframe width="100%" height="400" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/HSsqzzuGTPo?wmode=opaque" loading="lazy" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

      </li>
```

Comment: 'iframe' is a string. Why jQuery method `.closest()` would be available on a string?

Comment: Instead of `!'iframe'.closest('li active')`, try `!frames[i].closest('li active')`